# Rails4: Add custom action to nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Model:**

```
Supplier has_many Materials
Material belongs_to Supplier
```

I added a custom action to material

I added routes for materials in route.rb:

```
resources :suppliers do
  resource :materials, only:[:smindex]do
    get 'smindex', on: :member
  end
end
```

I hope to get path like this :

```
supplier_materials GET    /suppliers/:supplier_id/materials(.:format) materials#smindex
```

but I just get this:

```
smindex_supplier_materials GET    /suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/smindex(.:format) materials#smindex
```

Anybody could let me know how to get rid of the smindex in front of here `smindex_supplier_materials`

and smindex in the end of here

```
/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/smindex(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change routes to:

```
resources :suppliers do
  get :materials, to: 'materials#smindex'
end
```

This will generate following route for you

```
supplier_materials GET /suppliers/:supplier_id/materials(.:format)  materials#smindex
```